# Ring Group @ Asterisk. Is it possible to use dial and goto on the same priority?

Tags: asterisk

I need to create a ring group (222) which would dial several SIP accounts, and PSTN numbers as well.

For PSTN I have a different context (ToPSTN) with it's own billing rules, so the question is:
How can I ring several SIP acc's and PSTN's simultaneously ?

Here is how I am trying to do that:

```
exten => 222,1,Dial(SIP/ca-444&SIP/ca-433)
exten => 433,1,Goto(ToPSTN,0035853855453,1)
```

Or maybe it's possible to do several tasks at the same priority somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make dialing into dialplan instead of real channel driver you should use Local channel. This is how it look in your case:

> exten => 222,1,Dial(SIP/ca-444&Local/0035853855453@ToPSTN)

So first call goes to SIP peer ca-444 and second directly to dialplan extension 0035853855453 and context ToPSTN.